# Restore Ubuntu original packages after removing ppa

Tags: apt, php, ppa, restore

I'm running finally Ubuntu 16.04 and installed the PPA from "ppa:ondrej/php".
Some weeks ago I remove that PPA because I changed to PHPBREW.
Now tha I'm using PHPBREW with PHP 7 I got some older projects which needs PHP 5.6.
But PHPBREW can't install PHP 5.6 because some packages are now owned by deb.sury.org and their version is much higher then then the original from Ubuntu 16.04.
As an example I have openssl 1.1.0f (deb.sury.org). Ubuntu 16.04 original package is 1.0.2g. Now I want to reinstall that package but Ubuntu won't let me to change that version.
Also there are some dependencies like libssl1.1 (again sury) instead of libssl1.0.2.

Is there any chance to get rid of every "sury"-package without reinstalling the whole system?
In my directory "/var/lib/apt/lists/" there is no "sury" to search for so I don't know how many packages are replaced by that ppa.